# Running an executable jar file built from a gradle based project

Tags: java, jar, gradle

I have a standalone project which is gradle based. When I do gradle build, the jar is generated under build/libs. How do I run this executable jar from command line? I tried : `java -cp build/libs/foo.jar full.package.classname` but I get noClassFoundException for the classes that were imported. How do I include dependent jars as part of classpath?

Comment: if you have an executable jar just use java -jar path-to-jar-file

Comment: Consider using application plugin. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: @Satya I get Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute error. When I run it using gradle (gradle run -DmainClass=<main_package_class>), it adds all jars (from ~/.gradle/caches directory) as part of classpath. Is there any other way of doing it with just the jar file that is built?

Comment: @Jayan I'm using application plugin to build and run on my local dev box. But on a production environment, gradle may not be there and I would have to just copy the jar to prod and run.

Comment: As of topic: use `gradlew` if you are not sure about availability of gradle

Comment: `java -jar build/libs/foo.jar` is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 22):

Since question is marked with gradle tag I assume you want to run jar from gradle build. I also assume you use `java` plugin for your gradle build.

Add next lines in your gradle:

```
task runFinalJar(type: JavaExec) {
   classpath = files('build/libs/foo.jar')
   classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   main = full.package.classname
}
```

You can now include your task to the build process:

```
build.dependsOn.add("runFinalJar")
```

Or just run it form command line:

```
gradle build runFinalJar
```

**UPDATE**: It is cleaner to use application plugin [as Peter suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20731688/392847)

Comment: Actually I'm able to run it successfully from gradle build. I would create a jar file using gradle build and this jar would be deployed on production environment which does not necessarily have gradle installed. So the question is how to run this jar? Gradle internally includes all dependent jars (from ~/.gradle directory) as part of classpath. So I wanted to know is there any way of doing it easily with just the jar file.

Comment: `gradlew` will help you with gradle installation

Comment: I would not want to install gradle on prod environment. I found a work around though. I was able to copy all dependent jars for my project into a directory by writing a simple gradle task. Now, my jar and its dependency jars are available in a directory : ~/myproject/build/libs. If I do java -cp *.jar <main_package_classname> I get a NoClassDefinedException on my main class. I verified that my project's jar is in the same directory and also has the main class. What am I missing?

Comment: I would like to know the same thing. I also can't figure out how to get gradle to produce a fully packaged jar that can be run without gradlew. How do you get the dependency classes to be bundled in the output jar?

Comment: This line: classpath = file('build/libs/foo.jar') gives me a "Cannot cast object 'path to jar' with class "java.io.File" to class 'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection' - so I am guessing it should not be file(...) but something like fileset(...) (I dont think fileset exists, but something though, so something else that does exist in gradle instead)?

Comment: My fault! Updated answer. Try the application plugin mentioned by Peter

Answer (score 13):

Add a simple task to run jar

```
task runJar(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "-jar";
    args jar.archivePath
}
```

**UPDATE**: `jar.archivePath` is now deprecated, you can use `jar.archiveFile.get()`

```
task runJar(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "-jar";
    args jar.archiveFile.get()
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Either use the [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#application_plugin) to create an archive containing your code, its dependencies, and startup scripts, or create an executable fat Jar. The latter shouldn't be done in the naive way, but with the [gradle-one-jar](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) (or a similar) plugin.

Comment: This answer could be improved by telling the reader how to identify "the naive way".  For instance, is using `from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar` a naive way?

Answer (score 6):

I think that the answers go beyond what the question actually is.  The question is, or can be restated as, how to run a JAR which gradle builds.

The questioner states that they've tried `java -cp build/libs/foo.jar full.package.classname` to no avail.

The correct syntax is `java -jar build/libs/foo.jar`, or if the JAR is right there, obviously it's  then just `java -jar foo.jar` as normally.

The question should be edited for clarity, IMHO.

Comment: The issue is that doesn't add the dependencies that could be declared in the build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie, so my explanations here will be simplistic. My `build.gradle` file contains only one line: `apply plugin: 'java'`. I have a `hello world` java code in `src/main/java/org/dx/test/App.java`. From the command shell, I typed: `gradle build`. And then I saw this jar file magically created:

```
build/libs/helloworld.jar
```

All of the above answers did not work. What worked for me is:

```
java -cp build/libs/helloworld.jar org.dx.test.App
```

Now, I know gradle is full of sorcercy so I am sure my situation may not fully reflect your situation. The actions are did were:

1. Create that one line `build.gradle` file
2. Create the `App.java` under the doctor's prescribed folder location
3. Type `gradle build`

Answer (score 0):

The **application** Gradle plugin adds a task called **run** to a Gradle module.

With this plugin a Gradle module named **app** can be executed like so:

```
./gradlew :app:run
```

**Output**

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 534ms
17 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 16 up-to-date
 ~/Workspace/so20728621 $ ./gradlew clean :app:run

> Task :app:run
[main] INFO rbento.app.Main - Running...
```

The relevant settings can be found below:

**~/Workspace/so20728621/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'so20728621'

include('app')
```

**~/Workspace/so20728621/app/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'rbento.app.Main'
}
```

**Environment**

```
Gradle: 8.1.1
JVM:    17.0.6 (Azul Systems, Inc. 17.0.6+10-LTS)
OS:     Mac OS X 13.4.1 aarch64
```

Answer (score -1):

To run a jar in terminal, first build a jar using "gradle clean build" then , navigate to -> build -> distribution -> `unzip <filename>.zip file`
-> cd to unzipped file
-> `cd bin`
there will be 2 files - projectname & <projectname.bat> run the jar with ./projectname

If there are some args to be passed to main method use : run the jar with ./projectname params