# How to run executable-jar file in spring-boot application outside eclipse when its built using gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle, executable-jar

I am able to run the spring-boot (using gradle build) application using Eclipse IDE and http://localhost:8080/ runs the app fine without any problem.

I'm now trying to run the same application using command line like this - `java -jar foodapp` and I get the output similar to the one I get when run in Eclipse as following:

Sandeeps-MacBook-Pro:libs sandeepamarnath$ `java -jar foodapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-09-12 20:20:17.292  INFO 785 --- [           main] c.s.foodapp.FoodappApplication           : Starting FoodappApplication on Sandeeps-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 785 (/Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/ShareMyRecipe-Java/foodapp/build/libs/foodapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by sandeepamarnath in /Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/ShareMyRecipe-Java/foodapp/build/libs)
2019-09-12 20:20:17.295  INFO 785 --- [           main] c.s.foodapp.FoodappApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-12 20:20:17.797  INFO 785 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-12 20:20:17.863  INFO 785 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 59ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
2019-09-12 20:20:18.184  INFO 785 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df477ee1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-12 20:20:18.455  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-12 20:20:18.485  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-12 20:20:18.485  INFO 785 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-09-12 20:20:18.737  INFO 785 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2019-09-12 20:20:18.901  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-12 20:20:18.901  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1572 ms
2019-09-12 20:20:19.128  INFO 785 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-09-12 20:20:19.868  INFO 785 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-09-12 20:20:19.919  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-09-12 20:20:19.992  INFO 785 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-09-12 20:20:19.994  INFO 785 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-09-12 20:20:20.164  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-09-12 20:20:20.441  INFO 785 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-09-12 20:20:22.047  INFO 785 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-09-12 20:20:22.705  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2a79d4b1, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7d42c224, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@20b12f8a, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@544820b7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@23d1e5d0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@68ad99fe, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@522a32b1, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5ddea849, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2e9fda69, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2e554a3b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2e61d218, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3f6db3fb]
2019-09-12 20:20:22.859  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-12 20:20:22.908  WARN 785 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-09-12 20:20:23.140  INFO 785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-09-12 20:20:23.142  INFO 785 --- [           main] c.s.foodapp.FoodappApplication           : Started FoodappApplication in 21.143 seconds (JVM running for 21.485)
2019-09-12 20:20:35.404  INFO 785 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-12 20:20:35.404  INFO 785 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-12 20:20:35.411  INFO 785 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
2019-09-12 20:20:35.579  INFO 785 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

But, When I run the `localhost:8080` in the browser I get error like below

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Sep 12 20:20:40 EDT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp
```

Though I am getting the same message in eclipse and command line, when the app is run, why is that I am not able to get the browser working the second time in the command line version. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your time.

My gradle file contains:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.sharemyrecipe.foodapp.FoodappApplication.java'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}


apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.sharemyrecipe'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl
    compile group: 'jstl', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-taglibs'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api'


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question, hope it might help someone. As mentioned in [Running an executable jar file built from a gradle based project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728621/running-an-executable-jar-file-built-from-a-gradle-based-project)

In build.gradle file I added

```
task runFinalJar(type: JavaExec) {
   classpath = files('build/libs/foo.jar')
   classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   main = 'com.sharemyrecipe.foodapp.FoodappApplication'
}
```

And in the command line (in the folder where gradlew exists), executed the command

```
./gradlew runFinalJar
```

and now it runs perfectly fine. Thanks to Eugen Martynov